# Display images from the database in foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I try to get the images from the table
 "products_category_images" by picking the ID from "products_category".

I tried to use foreach in foreach, as well as cycle for.

This is the class processing code:

```
function fetchCategoryTree($parent = 0, $spacing = '', $user_tree_array = '') {

    if (!is_array($user_tree_array))
        $user_tree_array = array();


    $fastQuery = fastQuery('SELECT `id` FROM `products_category` ORDER BY `id` DESC');

    foreach($fastQuery as $key => $values) {

        ## PICTURES ## 
        $sqlImage = "SELECT * FROM `products_category_images` WHERE `uniqueID` = '".$values['id']."' LIMIT 1"; 
        $resImage = mysql_query($sqlImage); 

    }
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `products_category_translate` WHERE `parentID` = $parent AND `language` = '".lang()."'";
                    $query = mysql_query($sql);

                    while (($row = mysql_fetch_object($query))||($row = mysql_fetch_object($resImage))) {
                        $user_tree_array[] = array("id" => $row->id, "image" => $spacing . $row->image, "uniqueID" => $row->uniqueID, "title" => $spacing . $row->title);
                        $user_tree_array = fetchCategoryTree($row->uniqueID, $spacing . '-- ', $user_tree_array);
                    }

    return $user_tree_array;
}
```

And here I get the result:

```
        $categoryList = fetchCategoryTree();
        foreach($categoryList as $cl) { 
            echo '<a href="'.$g['url'].''.languageURL('0', 'products/'.$cl['uniqueID'].'/'.convertToURL($cl['title']).'.html').'"><img src="'.$g['url'].'uploads/products-category/'.$cl['image'].'" style=" width: 85px; height: 45px; display: inline;" class="img-responsive"> '.$cl['title'].'</a><br>';
            echo ''.$rowfastQuery['id'].'';
        }
```

I tried to take the ID and increment at the end of the cycle, but it did not work again.

Comment: You are defining `$user_tree_array` twice in your while loop.

Comment: Yes, that's because I bring subcategories with it.

Comment: Well when you do that you are over writing the previous values.

Comment: You are using `$restImage` in  `while loop` but your while loop is out of the `foreach` that means you will be getting only the last value generated by `foreach` in `$restImage`

Comment: When I get him in foreach I get the following error: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1653342208) (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in

Comment: Create sub function for `while` loop and call that in `foreach`.

Comment: I rework code and now return : 11111111111111112222222222222222333333333333333344444444444444446666666666666666777777 ... 161616